# agregar spinner a datatable v1.10

Tags: datatables

Necesito agregar un spinner o "loading" a mi datatable , he intentado sin resultados, existirá por defecto en datatable ?

He intentado con esto:

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
                "paging":   true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info":     false,        
                "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
                processing: true,
                "language": {
                  "processing": " Waiting..." //add a loading image,simply putting <img src="loader.gif" /> tag.
              }

          });


$('#table').dataTable( {
                    "paging":   true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info":     false,      
                    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
                    processing: true,
                    'language':{ 
                       "loadingRecords": "&nbsp;",
                       "processing": "Loading..."
                    }




              });
```

Comment: El código que publicas no muestra lo que has intentado, por favor agrega un __[mcve]__.

Comment: language: { "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando..." } Creo que es eso. Pero no es un Spinner, solamente te sale en letras.